# winforms profiling - dotTrace 3.1 or Ants 4.3

Tags: .net, optimization, memory, cpu, profiler

are there any particular features in one versus another that would help me decide which to purchase for a winforms app.

I am looking for both memory, cpu, performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I red various reviews. Somebody liked [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and somebody [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm). I would recommend you to download trial versions of both and try it for yourself. They are not cheap and therefore it is better to know what you're buying.

(I personally use dotTrace.)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't WinForms-specific, but you might find the answers to [What are some good .NET profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) useful.

RedGate's [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants%5Fprofiler/index.htm) profiler and JetBrains' [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) seem like the two most popular commercial products.